# Faster Process suggestions for Interior Renders

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

I'd love to get pointed in the right direction on this. I need to make some interior renders for a project at work, but my process has always involved unwrapping and then texturing. But it'll be 80% concepting and idea generation, so I would need to model soooo much crap and that process seems so backwards in this time crunch! The Uv and texturing portion is what Im slowest at , wondering if there is a decent process that can skip alltogether or drastically speed that up.

I dont need to go for insane photorealism. Would nodes be the direction, or some other trick or method I should pursue?

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't just re-use the same scene when experimenting with textures? And if you're trying to make room concepts, you could also try "blocking it out" (basically just make the rough shape out of basic shapes) so you don't have to make as many detailed models.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating scenes multiple times, each with similar ideas/looks, why not create an asset pack?

Firstly, create your tables, windows, chairs, vases, couches, curtains, etc. and put them on a single .blend file, group them by object type, then import the file whenever you want to use them. It saves loads of wasted time.

Secondly, You may know this already but I'm going to mention it just in case. Use the boolean modifier for windows. It's a time saver. This is a great thing to use on the asset pack windows as well.

Thirdly, if you don't want to use an asset pack and need to create unique objects whilst cutting back on time, create objects with single colours or built-in textures like noise. This often means you do not need to worry about UV unwrapping. This though may not be what you are looking for but it is quite a viable option.

Fourthly, whenever possible, keep your objects in a cube-like fashion. UV unwrapping becomes 100X easier. Plus, when your items are like this, you can use smart UV unwrap and it normally works a treat. If your meshes become complex, take a look at the decimate modifier. It may help, or it may not.

Fifth, Create all your models, then texture. I know this may sound stupid and people will argue with me on this one. I find this something of personal help. It may work for you, it may not. I just find that you can keep yourself in the modelling headspace much easier if you're not switching between two tasks. Plus, if you find an object doesn't quite work with the scene, you don't have to re UV unwrap it when you're done. 'OHH, but it's not the same without colour'. That, my friend, is what my recommendation 3 is for. Add solid colours before you texture. Ensure everything works well together.

Sixth. Simple but helpful. Use backface culling on the walls, floor and roof so you can see your scene from the outside.

Finally, use the mirror modifier. The number of times I see people using the mirror modifier to create their object, to only apply it and UV unwrap the whole mesh. If you have used a mirror modifier, or can use one, it can halve the time spent on each object. Even if you need to texture each side slightly differently, (the left handle needs to be blue, the right red) still UV unwrap with the mirror modifier. Once you have unwrapped, apply the modifier and both sides UV will appear on top of one another. Move the handle to where you want it.

Tadaa, Seven wonderful tips, as you requested :P

You may use them, you may not, but all my recommendations are up to the preferences that suit the user.

BTW, I would love to see a render of your scene when you are done. I love the look of interior designs :D

Good luck with your project and I hope I helped,

BFB

Quick afterthought:

If you want quick, less realistic renders and the option to look in realtime, I recommend checking out Blender 2.8 and its new feature EEVEE.
It does take a while to get used to the new interface and it is still in production, riddled with bugs, but for what you are doing, I believe it will help you allot, particularly with texturing.